# Suddenly today, no HDMI on both Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7. What is HDA driver?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, sound, hdmi

In the past, I just plug in hdmi, then boot laptop, and I have display on tv. Today my tv reads as "No Signal". When I go into "sound" on dashboard, there is No HDMI option. I don't understand what could have changed in the past few days. I also have Windows 7 on this machine, and I have same issue on there as well. In Ubuntu I scanned for drivers, and it asked if I wanted to activate HDA driver for DKMS. I'm not sure what that is. I googled and it looks like an audio driver. In Windows, Its says driver is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Well I fixed it,  and why this worked,  I have no idea.  I went into Windows,  device manager,  device adapters,  and disabled then re enabled my intel graphics.  I then booted into ubuntu,  and hdmi worked perfectly again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same issue in Ubuntu as well as Windows than it is highly unplausible that it is a software issue.

Check your BIOS settings and if they are OK you might have a hardware failure.